# "Where will I be," "where will I get to," "what place will I reach": What's the best way to ask?

Tags: word-choice, questions

What's the most natural way to complete this question (the person asking this question wants to know the name of a place)?

> If I keep going south from here, […]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most natural completion (in speech) would be, in my opinion

> If I keep going south from here, where will I get to?

or

> If I keep going south from here, where do I get to?

Answer (score 7):

"[End up](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/end_up)" is natural in this context (for my American English). I would say:

> If I keep going south from here, where will I end up?

"End up":

- does not imply anything about what type of destination it is, like whether it's a general area, a city, a building, store, neighborhood. You can "end up" in New York, at a grocery store, in Canada, on Elm Street, or in a bad neighborhood.
- has the connotation of arriving at the destination without first knowing what the destination is, making it fitting for this context.
- does not imply how far you will go, or that you will even know when to stop, or that you are even going to a specific place.

This puts the burden on the answerer to decide how to answer the question (as opposed to "which place will I reach?" which limits answers to places as @n0nChun says.

"Where will I be" to me seems slightly less open-ended than "end up", though almost the same. I don't think I've ever heard "get to", but I suspect it's regional and equivalent to "end up". I don't see a fitting wiktionary definition for "[get to](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_to)" though.

Answer (score 1):

> If I keep going south from here,

- what establishment will I be at?
- what what building will I be at?
- what landmark will I arrive at?

Comment: Thank you for these answers. is it possible to complete this question with something similar in meaning, but without a noun?

Answer (score 1):

I think both of the following are correct. Others, correct me if I'm wrong.

> If I keep going South from here, what place will I reach?
>
> If I keep going South from here, where will I get to?

On a sidenote, the answer to the second question may not specify a particular place. Like, the person may say, you'll get to a dead end. If you really want a particular place, I guess you should frame your questions more specifically like in (1)